# No full-screen with pepperflash in Firefox

Tags: firefox, adobe-flash

Because the use of the default `flashplugin-installer` v.11.2 entails [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/562035/47206), and in a more severe form, as the answer accepted there doesn't work, I have preferred, instead of digging farther in that direction, to use [this solution to install Chrome's pepperflash plugin in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/a/562272/47206).

[image]

That works, excepting the full-screen... The screen is black or in some cases there is a ridiculously tiny remnant of the video in the top left corner :)

[image]

---

There is a configuration file that can be downloaded from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin/master/data/freshwrapper.conf.example) and should be renamed to `freshwrapper.conf` and put in `~/.config/freshwrapper-data/`.

But I don't know which parameters to change there.

(I'm in eOS Freya - based on *ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: FWIW, anything based on Ubuntu is not Ubuntu if it is not on the approved supported variants list.

Comment: [the comment was made due to this comment you made on Ask Ubuntu that links back here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562271/can-i-use-chromes-pepper-flash-with-firefox/562272#comment928832_562272)

Comment: @ThomasW. -  given that it is not impossible for the problem that I report here to appear in Ubuntu proper too, take a look at the answer that I got below. It works.

Comment: post a comment with your-down vote please, help me improve the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and found a way to make it work:

- In the folder `~/.config/` create a new text file called `freshwrapper.conf`.
- Copy and paste [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin/master/data/freshwrapper.conf.example) inside the new file.
- Look for `fullscreen_width` and `fullscreen_height`. Change these settings from `0` to `<display_width - 1>` and `<display_height - 1>` and it should work. Note that you have to enter the actual values for the size of your display. You also can't use the full size of your display because it seems like that's what's causing the problem.